# Would It Be wrong if I stopped doing what isn’t required of me?

Tags: work-environment, termination, safety

So basically, I work at a private chiropractic office/physical rehab clinic for about 7 years now. My job title at the start has been “floater” (whatever that means) and throughout the years my tasks have drastically changed from one thing to another. (Not the problem.)

its not secret that I’m good with tech stuff and I love to help people when it involves technology since I can find more personal experience to learn if I don’t know the answer. However, my official job duties have recently come down to me doing Wc billing, posting checks, and dealing with wc mail and extra (which it wasn’t even attempted to train me on how to read them so that’s backed up)

Because I’m good at computers and tech and whatnot, somehow anything new system related, passwords, fixing things, questions, and all the other stuff related to basically ITT have been going to me and my responsibility(free) and saves them the trouble and funds on calling their real ITT guys as well as stops me from doing my work and backs me up.

Upon taking some initiatives, I’ve managed to try and make things better and fix things to bring more money that we were losing out on (missing info, blank insurances, inability to print on correct forms, just wrong info in general) which painted my supervisor in a bad light for “reasons”( not living up to her word or proof that she can’t handle everything she makes look fine).

So now my supervisor has been on a silent rampage, looking over my shoulder, talking behind my back, asking what I’m doing and who told me to do it, waiting till I leave to show Work to others that I did not do because she gave it to me little by little throughout the day, waiting till I left to invite EVERYONE in the office to an outing of fun and drinking for administrators day.

Would I be wrong if I just completely stopped helping EVERYONE with the tech stuff? Could I get fired for it? Is there anything I can do to fight back in some way?

My office has WAY MORE PROBLEMS, but yeah.

Comment: What location is work?

Comment: You may also want to consider anonymising this question.

Comment: "`My office has WAY MORE PROBLEMS`" - why are you still there?

Comment: the location is NYC - Bronx. 
Thanks for the anonymous tip. 
im still here because aside from management which is terrible, i actually like my coworkers, its a 5 minute walk from home, and sadly i guess im just comfortable there at this point....

Answer (score 2):

This is not an easy situation for you. You will have some bad outcome, whatever you do. But the bad outcome may lead to something beneficial, though.

The most important for you is to decide what you actually want to do. Then go to your boss and have a discussion on the topic, and tell him  her that you want to concentrate only on [whatever you want to do].

If the boss agrees, everyone is happy.

If not, theme might be room for negotiation. I do Y bot for [this] salary and [these] benefits.

Worst case (but not necessarily inherently bad): find a new job.

---

If you just stop doing IT stuff, you might have more serious problems, as to being accused of all kinds of bad behavior. Before you create some havoc for them, discuss with your boss. If needed, with the boss of your boss (after you talk to your boss).

Comment: In this case, you seem to be in the "worst case" situation described. However, it would not hurt (much) to have a discussion, though. People can be very surprising sometimes - usually for the bad, but sometimes for the good also.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be fired? Yes: most employment in the USA is "at will" -- either you or your employer can end your employment at any time for any reason or no reason.

You didn't say whether you hope to save your current job.

If you do: there are a couple of things you could try.

1. Communicate! Have a private conversation with your supervisor. Say something like, *"when you look over my shoulder and talk about me behind my back, it makes me think there's something wrong with the way I do my work. But that confuses me, because you have not told me what I'm doing wrong. Can you help me do a better job and serve you and this clinic better?"*    This puts the issue out there on the table in a professional way, and invites your supervisor to do her job as supervisor.
2. Communicate! Ask somebody in an executive position (one of the doctors, maybe?) for advice about getting along better with your supervisor. Notice you're asking an executive for advice, not complaining about your supervisor. If the executives are worth their salt, they'll know what's going on, or figure it out quickly.

Keep in mind that insurance billing is a perennial pain in the ...neck, and your supervisor has probably been in the trenches getting this thankless job done so long that she's emotionally stuck. It may be hard to communicate to her that you're trying to make her, and your whole organization, successful. But you can try.

You could "work to rule," refraining from doing things that aren't in your job description. But your morale and your clinic's business will suffer if you do that.

Finally, with the skills you mention, there are certainly other health-care businesses that would jump at the chance to get you. So, you are not stuck.